# Droplets and Billing cycle in the digital ocean

Tags: laravel, cloud, devops, digital-ocean

I want to deploy my existing Laravel application in the Digital Ocean and this is my first time to go live. I'm choosing droplets shared CPU $5/month my questions are.

1. Is $5/month is exactly the amount that I will pay for the monthly bill?. If my application is online/accessible forever do I still get to pay $5/month?.
2. As stated above that I'm using the Laravel framework, can I ssh in the server and install dependencies without a problem?, also can I change the PHP version in the server?.

Please help me this is my first time and I have no idea what to choose if shared or dedicated CPU'S.

Note: My Laravel application is only for my personal use.

Here is my screenshots.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Bitfumes (on YouTube) made an interesting series on deploying Laravel on Digital Ocean. You may have a look at the first 2 videos that will help you out with this choice. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlZk0BkX6XY&list=PLe30vg_FG4OQ6Qc5sanScihpmQAlBiexl

Comment: @DimitriMostrey, thanks I will look on this too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the price that you will pay each month unless you turn on features like automatic backup and etc. which add up a couple of extra $.

You can, however, get billed more if you go over the droplets outbound data transfer. Check it [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/billing/bandwidth/). But since you said it's only for your personal use, no worries there.

Yes, you can ssh into your server and install whatever you need on it (composer, database, PHP libs).

For every package, you are still billed hourly up to the end of the month which roughly equates to the price on that screenshot. That means that you can play around with your droplet, see how it works, and if you change your mind, you can always delete it, and only be billed for the number of hours that you used it.

Comment: thank you for the reply, what do you mean `and only be billed for the number of hours that you used it.` you mean ssh to the server or accessing the site?

Comment: I'm afraid if they will charge me if my site is always online even I'm not accessing the ssh. just accessing only my site login and inputting some data, I want my site always online. should I be worry about this or not?

Comment: @jemz I believe you shh-ing into the server will not have any meaningful impact on the bandwidth usage. You would need serious monthly traffic in order to go over 1TB. However, you are billed hourly even if there is no usage on the server but it will not go over monthly price unless you go over the bandwidth. By the server usage, I refer to people actually visiting your application and server responding to requests.

Comment: @jemz just to clarify, you can at any point of the month destroy your droplet and the billing is stopped. So let's say that your droplet was working for five days. You will be charged days * hours * package rate. You will not pay $5 if you didn't use it for a full month